# Save Canvas Drawing on Image in Android

Tags: android, image, imageview, save, android-canvas

I'm working on an application in which I'v a custom ImageView. Using custom imageview I can drag,zoom, and paste text over over it (using its onDraw() function). Now at the end I want to put all the canvas drawing over image and want to save it in the file system. I have tried imageView.getDrawingCache() method but it does not fulfill my requirements as when I zoom out the it captures black sides of the image too. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create or load your Bitmap.
2. Create Canvas.
3. Set the Bitmap as target for this canvas. [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#setBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29)
4. Draw your text using the canvas.

Now your image stored in Bitmap has drawn stuff on top of it.

Comment: if you have any example then provide him